# Totally confused by actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have this code in ActionScript 2, it animates to audio input in my VJ software.

**Question:**
How do I re-write this as AS3 code?

```
var audiofft1 :Number;

circle1.onEnterFrame = function(){
    
this._xscale = audiofft1
this._yscale = audiofft1
    

}

stop()
```

Comment: Which part is difficult? Did you create a variable in AS3? Can't create an Event listener for EnterFrame? Can't change X or Y scale? (is called `scaleX` and `scaleY` in AS3)? Do you need the `stop()` command?

Comment: It's all difficult, as I don't understand any of it. I copied the code from the coder a few years ago when I was using flash with AS2.

Comment: **(1)** _"I don't understand any of it"_ All the code does is create a variable (`audiofft1`) then uses an EnterFrame event function to change scale of the `circle1` object. You can use Google with keyword **AS3** like: [AS3 declare variable](https://www.google.com/search?q=AS3+declare+variable) to know how to write a variable in AS3 code. **(2) PS:** I'm not convinced that shown code is animating anything (the number is never updated to change sizes). You can read up on AS3 based [audio visualization tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=as3+audio+visualization).

Comment: Thank you for this information. it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The migration es this:

```
var audiofft1 :Number;
circle1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFramaCircle1);

function onEnterFramaCircle1(e:Event):void{
        this._xscale = audiofft1;
        this._yscale = audiofft1;
};

stop();
```

But what do you try to do?

Comment: I'm hoping to recreate some sound reactive visuals to play in Arkaos.

Comment: @RedDog you could have mentioned in your Question that you're following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEsZ0C5rBSw&ab_channel=ArKaos) and that `audiofft1` is updated by Arkaos itself. Normally in AS3 something like `this._xscale` would not work (gives compiler error) hence my warning that the code you showed won't animate anything.

Comment: My apologies.. I'll be more precise in future.

Comment: @RedDog No worries, just saying it could have led to a misunderstanding (of code expectations). Technical info (thing X does what? where? why?) will help others to give a more correct Answer for your situation. Just saying for if you have future questions. Your problem is fixed and I learnt something new with this Arkaos thing (gunna test my funk breaks)